# Empty titles in new answers to questions more than 30 days old

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

The anchor titles on the [New Answers to Questions More Than 30 Days Old](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) page are empty.

e.g:

```
<a href="/questions/2948097//7964162#7964162" class="answer-hyperlink "></a>
```

Comment: The link returns me a "Page Not Found" error. Is the link only for 10k users?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - yes, it is one of the 10K tools

Comment: k.... looking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed <s>in the next build</s> now. A cog fell off the machine.

(in other words, the cause/fix isn't particularly interesting/illuminating; just: a bug)