# Eeeek! Where did the answers with extreme votes go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty titles in new answers to questions more than 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110762/empty-titles-in-new-answers-to-questions-more-than-30-days-old)

Either I seriously need to get my recently-checked-up eyesight checked *again*, or there's something amiss with the 10k tools:

[image: stackoverflowscreenshot]

I've tried expanding the list of answers, to no avail. I've even tilted the flatscreen monitor to see if it's a contrast issue or not. I've clicked everywhere in the whitespace, expecting unicorns to jump out any minute. But alas, there's really nothing there. I hardly think that this is intentional.

Note that the "Most commented" section and the "Most edited" section is missing some links too, although it's clearly not as bad as the "Answers with extreme votes" section.

I can reproduce the bug in IE 9, Firefox 7, and Chrome 15. The revision number of the site was 2011.11.1.2 when I took the screenshot.

Comment: Yep, repro on Super User.

Comment: I wonder if it is somehow related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110762/empty-titles-in-new-answers-to-questions-more-than-30-days-old

Comment: I like it. Much cleaner :)

Comment: Your freehand circle is missing the missing titles in the "Most commented" area as well.

Comment: I like it, too. 95% of the noise on the average SO overview page is caused by question titles. Removing them is a logical step

Comment: Answers with extreme votes? More like extreme votes without answers. 16! 14! −3!

Comment: @JoshLee 16! would be extreme voting indeed: 20922789888000 (eeek), [`-3! == gamma(-2) == complex infinity`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28-2%29)?

Comment: @sehe: I think the factorial has a higher precedence than the negative sign. So it would be `-(3!) == -6`, no?

Comment: @Insilico: Actually, I think Josh wrote `&mdash;` there (-3 vs. −3), which doesn't have formal meaning in programming languages. I assumed mathematical notation

Comment: k... looking...

Comment: Fixed next build