# Badge list view broken for Answer Badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, nice-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty titles in new answers to questions more than 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110762/empty-titles-in-new-answers-to-questions-more-than-30-days-old)

**EDIT** I realize (a bit late) now that this might be by design. In that case, this question may be converted into a feature request - having a description of some kind is really handy to find that one answer you know you had a badge for.

---

In the overview screen for badges, the titles of answers are normally listed. However, this appears to be broken for answer badges:

For example refer to Jeff's nice-answer report:

- https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/?userid=1    # nice answer
- https://stackoverflow.com/badges/24/?userid=1    # good answer

The titles are missing <sup><sub>(I can't upload screenshots from where I'm at)</sub></sup>

By contrast, the titles are shown for question-badges

- https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/?userid=1    # good question

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110770/eeeek-where-did-the-answers-with-extreme-votes-go, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110762/empty-titles-in-new-answers-to-questions-more-than-30-days-old

Comment: This is the same fundamental bug as in the 10k tools - the bit of code that renders a particular flavor of links for answers got.... rusty. Thank you for reporting it, though. This will be fixed in the next deploy

Comment: @MarcGravell: cheers - good work!